# How Scale context from center in Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm drawing with Core Graphics and I need to scale down the current context.
I use the CGContextScaleCTM function but this use de origin and not the center.
How can I make scale from center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have scaled you can use `CGContextTranslateCTM` to move the context to wherever you like.

Comment: You can also do this before you scale. In fact, I'd do both: Translate by half the width and height of the view's bounds (which puts the origin in the view's center), scale, then translate back by half of the scaled width and height (you will have to figure up the last part yourself—`bounds` will still return the same numbers). The last step puts the center of your scaled rectangle in the center of the view.

Answer (score 3):

Change constant as required.

```
let percentScale : CGFloat = 0.8
context.translateBy(x: rect.size.width * (1.0 - percentScale) * 0.5, y: rect.size.height * (1.0 - percentScale) * 0.5)
context.scaleBy(x: percentScale, y: percentScale)
// ...draw into context
```